# WebSockets with Spring/STOMP/SockJS

Tags: spring, websocket, stomp, sockjs

My Connection to websocket as below :

```
var sockJSEndpoint = "/myproject/mywebsocket";
var socket = new SockJS(sockJSEndpoint);
stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);      
stompClient.connect({}, function (frame) {
    console.log('Connected : ' + frame);
    stompClient.subscribe('/topic/id/', function (data) {
        requestId = getRequestId(data.body);
        stompClient.subscribe('/topic/progress/' + id, function(data) {
            progressHandler(data.body,id);
        });
    });
});
```

This code works fine on the mac but when deployed to Linux the `/topic/id/` call does not return and response and hence the second call does not get triggered. And this happens only for the first request .Subsequent requests go through fine , as soon as the first call get triggered it returns the Id and attaches to next call and then the progress can be tracked. Any idea why it fails the first time ?

Any help is appreciated.